# Laravel localization files with database

Tags: database, laravel, localization

I want to make multilanguage site with laravel with [en:es] language. I created  en and es folders  in lang folder. Then i created translate.php file in those folder. File looks like.

```
<?php

return [
    'identificator' => 'text',
];
```

How to import all identificators and text to database table for CRUD and export'em back to translate.php file?

Answer (score 1):

**The solution is here in [Github](https://github.com/Waavi/translation)**

The content in the languages table is:

```
| id | locale | name    |
-------------------------
| 1  | en     | english |
| 2  | es     | spanish |
```

The relevant content in the language_entries table is:

```
| id | locale | namespace | group       | item            | text                    |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | en     | *         | validations | missing.name    | Name is missing         |
| 2  | en     | *         | validations | missing.surname | Surname is missing      |
| 3  | en     | *         | validations | min_number      | Number is too small     |
| 4  | es     | *         | validations | missing.name    | Falta nombre            |
| 5  | es     | *         | validations | missing.surname | Falta apellido          |
```

Output for different keys with es locale:

```
    trans('validations.missing.name');   //    'Falta nombre'
    trans('validations.min_number');     //    'Number is too small'
    trans('validations.missing.email');  //    'missing_email'
```